# MobaXterm SSH-browser Permission denied

Tags: ssh, permissions, mobaxterm

Having an ssh session in MobaXterm I can see the directory structure, but the folder with the three files from above does not open in the toc, only an ls -l will show the content, and where everything belongs to root. Using whoami I can confirm that I am root, but I cannot open the directory in the toc and cannot download the directory. WHen I try to do so MobaXterm returns with
[Message from SSH-browser of tab #1]
scp: /ssl/wireguard/phone: Permission denied

I did not found any solution

Answer (score 0):

I created a folder with `chmod 777` permissions, through a `cp` command I can move it to my root of interest